# How to clean a Quran Mushaf when a cockroach went over it?

Tags: quran

Yesternight, I saw a cockroach walked on top of my Quran. It walked on top of only the outside cover and didn't go inside.It was the large American cockroach type.

I read online that insects which have a pure origin ( ie they come from a pure place such as trees,  ) are pure, while insects with an impure origin ( ie they come from dirty places such as sewers, toilets ) are impure.

I think the cockroach must be impure, because I have seen these type of cockroahces in the sewer and the bathroom.

So what should be done to clean the Quran ? Should I wipe it with a tissue or wipe it with tissue+water ?

Comment: Was the article you've read online about a Muslim perspective? Can you share it? The cockroach walked on a Moshaf not the qur'an. I don't see any real issue in that, but  if you want to clean it -expecting to have been touched by najasah- anything like wiping (with a dry or wet rag) would do. And Allah knows best.

Comment: Do not overthink!!!!!!!! Just wipe it with anything.